# How to write styles in flutter as classes

Tags: flutter, dart, class, user-interface, user-experience

Let's say I have a souple of components using the same styles but I want it to write as classes like in html and css

Is there a  way this is possible?
By the way I'm a noob to coding started a year ago I'm 14 years old

Comment: What you can do is create a new stateful or stateless class and only create the widget you need inside this class. This will reduce your burden or re-implementing the styles.

Comment: so no way to write as a class?

Comment: You can implement it as a class in Theme Data. Make all your widget's style in theme data and then use that using `Theme.of(context).yourTheme`. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

Comment: You can also write a custom `AppDecoration` class and write your style as a static property of that class.

Comment: "so no way to write as a class?" - write a class that extends `InheritedTheme` - check for example [ProgressIndicatorTheme](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6928314d505d2bb4777be05e45d7808a5aa91d2a/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/progress_indicator_theme.dart#L153)

Comment: would creating a singleton class with static textStyles fix the issue you're facing? if you want I can give you a sample code

Answer (score 1):

I have added an example for read only text field for your reference.

```
class ReadOnlyTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String label;
  final Function() onPressedCallback;
  const ReadOnlyTextWidget({
    required this.controller,
    required this.label,
    required this.onPressedCallback,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReadOnlyTextWidget> createState() => _ReadOnlyTextWidgetState();
}

class _ReadOnlyTextWidgetState extends State<ReadOnlyTextWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          label: Text(widget.label),
          hintText: 'Enter ${widget.label}',
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          icon: TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: widget.onPressedCallback,
            label: const Text('Refresh'),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
          )),
      readOnly: true,
    );
  }
}
```